# With Java11 and Maven, try to avoid jacoco and surefire exit error and run jacoco test coverage on Mac

Tags: java, maven, java-11, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

This seems to be an issue related to Mac, Java11.  I am trying to run source code and target as Java8 but my runtime is java 11

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T14:49:05-05:00)
Maven home: /Users/user/Documents/tools/apache-maven-3.5.3
Java version: 11.0.6, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.6.jdk/Contents/Ho

> > 

**Issue with Jacoco**

Now with this configuration, I cannot run jacoco,

Error is:  Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.

**Issue with Surefire error**

I also have to put this in my pom.xml to avoid an error below.

Added snippet.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- Remove snippet below, fix jacoco?  But get jdk11 error? -->
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now, I get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project pri-prospect-management-batch: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/user/git-main5/pri-prospect-management-batch/app/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 134
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
```

So I am trying to run jacoco, java11, surefire without errors.

Configs:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-clean-plugin-version>2.5</maven-clean-plugin-version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <maven-dependency-plugin-version>2.8</maven-dependency-plugin-version>
    <maven-install-plugin-version>2.4</maven-install-plugin-version>
    <maven-jar-plugin-version>2.4</maven-jar-plugin-version>
    <maven-resources-plugin-version>2.6</maven-resources-plugin-version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.12.4</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
    <maven-war-plugin-version>2.2</maven-war-plugin-version>
    <maven-ear-plugin-version>2.8</maven-ear-plugin-version>
    <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
    <org.springframework.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
    <jackson.version>2.11.2</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

...

Jacoco

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: On this line, was thinking of adding:

<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${argLine}</argLine>

but didn't help

Comment: Do you get another error if you satisfy Jacoco with an execution file?

Comment: I strongly to upgrade the whole plugins your are using as well as Maven itself and furthermore JaCoCo as well..

Comment: I will second the above comment, unless you upgrade jacoco and surefire plugin, you will get little to no help

Comment: Let me try to upgrade.  Also, what is the execution file and how to create it

Comment: jacoco and surefire are not at latest, still same issue